# laravel Vue.js : Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, error-handling

I am creating commenting system using Vue.js and laravel 5.8.
I want to show comments in blog post page (show.blade.php) but I got an error

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null"

In my chrome vue dev tool, I could get objects, but I cannot show comments.

> I want to retrieve and show user name and user's comment.

I am glad if someone helps me out.

comments.vue

```
<template>
<div class="commentarea" > 
    <div class="comment-posts" >
        <div class="user-comment-area" >
            <div class="user-post">
                <!---<img src="{{asset('people/person7.jpg')}}" class="image-preview__image">--->
                <input type="text" name="comment">
            </div>
            <div class="comments-buttons">
                <button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
                <button class="comment-button" type="submit">Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Comments ()</h4>

        <div class="reply-comment" v-if="comment.user" v-for="comment in comments.data">
                <div class="user-comment">
                <div class="user">
                    <!---<img src="{{ $comment->user->img }}" class="image-preview__image">--->
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name"></avatar>
                </div>
                <div class="user-name">
                    <span class="comment-name">{{ comment.user.name }}</span>
                    <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reply">
                <div class="seemorecomments">
                    <a href="">see more</a>
                </div>
                <button class="reply-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button  class="load">Load More</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
export default {
    props: ['post'],
    components: {
        Avatar
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchComments()
    },
    data: () => ({
        comments: {
            data: []
        }
    }),
    methods: {
        fetchComments() {
            axios.get(`/results/${this.post.id}/comments`).then((data) => {
                this.comments = data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('results/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@index');
```

ResultsController.php

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $recommended_posts = Post::latest()
                        ->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d'))
                        ->where('category_id','=',$post->category_id)
                        ->where('id','!=',$post->id)
                        ->limit(7)
                        ->get();

    // load the post comments here
    $post->load('comments');
    $posts['particular_post'] = $post;
    $posts['recommended_posts'] = $recommended_posts;

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

CommentsController.php

```
public function index(Post $post)
{
    return $post->comments()->with('user')->paginate(5);
}
```

comment.php

```
 protected $with = ['user'];
```

show.blade.php

```
<comments-component :post="{{ $posts['particular_post'] }}"></comments-component>
```

Comment: Can you provide a dump of what `fetchComments` returns in Vue? Seems like the relationship isn't being bought in

Answer (score 1):

You're getting data from axios, and use it like Paginator, but axios response a own AxiosResponse object, then, you have in AxiosResponse one object like

```
{
   status: 200,
   data : {}  <= Your paginator is here
}
```

I think is that the problem. You need to set to comments something like:

```
this.comments = data.data;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how can I show next 5 comments ?

Comment: You're asking duplicate questions @YoheiUmezu . You've already asked this in a separate thread.

Comment: Actually the diffrence is v-for="comment in comments.data". In my previous question, I could solve the problem. But I got an issue for paginating, so I changed v-for part.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu If you want to show the next 5 comments, you need to save the current page, and total pages, and depend of them, show a "Read more" button or something like that and load the next page.

Or course, your request need to receive the page param too.

Answer (score 0):

Taken [from the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for) (highlighting of the second paragraph by me):

> Using `v-if` and `v-for` together is **not recommended**. See the [style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) for further information.
>
> **When used together with v-if, v-for has a higher priority than v-if**. See the [list rendering guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) for details.

So, you cannot use the `comment` from the `v-for` statement, it's not available when `v-if` is being evaluated. Therefore it's undefined and cannot have a `user` property, which explains the error message.

See the proposed solutions linked to from the official docs and the quote above. You could for example have a computed property that pre-filters `comments.data` for only those commetns that have `user` set.

```
computed: {
  commentsWithUser: function() {
    return this.comments.filter(c => { return c.user });
  }
}
```

And then use `v-for="comment in commentsWithUser"` instead.

*Additional note:* You should also supply a `:key` value when using `v-for`. It has to be something unique for each rendered element, so if your comments have an ID, let's say in `comments.data[...].id`, then `:key="comment.id" v-for="comment in comments.data"` would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I could solve this by changing to v-for="comment in comments.data.data" :key="comment.id".